# Implementing a graph class in C++

Tags: c++, graph-theory

Here is my class:

```
template <class T>
class Vertex
{
private:
  T data;
  Vertex<T>* next;
public:
  friend class Graph;
  Vertex(T dat, Vertex<T>* nex)
  {   
    data=dat;  next = nex;
  }
};

template <class T>
class Graph
{
public:
  Vertex<T>* head;
  Graph() : head(NULL)
  {
  }

  void insert(T data)
  {
    Vertex<T>* ptr = new Vertex<T>(data, head);
    head = ptr;
  }
};
```

And main:

```
int main()
{
  Graph<int> graph;
  graph.insert(1);
}
```

When I compile it tells me this:

```
graph.h: In instantiation of ‘Vertex<int>’:
graph.h:30:   instantiated from ‘void Graph<T>::insert(T) [with T = int]’
main.cpp:6:   instantiated from here
graph.h:10: error: template argument required for ‘struct Graph’
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: friend class declaration is incomplete. You need to specify Graph<T> instead of just Graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to "forward declare" the `Graph` class when using it in a friend statement:

```
template <class T>
class Graph;

template <class T>
class Vertex
{
private:
//...
public:
friend class Graph<T>;
// ... and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, you need to provide the template arguments for the Graph class wherever you are using it. So, friend class declaration should have

```
friend class Graph<T>;
```

Instead of

```
friend class Graph;
```

Comment: Couple of chars lost... Edited, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is not need for the forward declaration. Declaration of friend creates forward declaration if a class or a function is not yet defined. Standard explictly states this. You should write:

```
template <class T> friend class Graph;
```

This will effectively declare all instantiations of `Graph` as friends of the current class.